# understanding basics of CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, context-free-language

Have just started the chapter about CFL in Sipser's book and already fail to understand the basics.

Let this be the grammar of some language:

```
S -> A0A 
A -> 00A | 11A | 10A | 01A | e
```

I am really confused about this A0A part. Does it mean that the left hand side from 0 should be always the same as the right hands side. Does this mean 00011 or 000 are not in this language then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `S` is any option you have for any `A`, followed by a single literal `0` and then another option for `A`.  Each `A` is independent.

The string `00011` is in the language because you can pick your two `A`s (for example) such that the first one is `00A` and the second one is `11A`.  If you pick recursively the empty string (`e`) for both of the "remaining" `A`s, when you concatenate everything you'll end up with the string `00011`.

You can do a similar thing to obtain the string `000`.

Answer (score 0):

A transforms to either empty, or two binary digits then A. It means that A transforms to any sequence of even number of binary digits.

S transforms to A, then 0, then A. This means that S is transforms to even number of binary digits, then 0, then even number of binary digits.  That is, S is any sequence of odd number of binary digits with 0 in the middle.

> Does it mean that the left hand side from 0 should be always the same as the right hands side.

No, why?  Two different A's can transform to different sequences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some reason I thought that they had to be same.